# How to Animate a UIView n number of times within a loop and track each animation event

Tags: ios, swift, animation

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
    // UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(3.0)

        self.leadng.constant = self.view.frame.size.width + self.vwObj.frame.size.width
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: { finished in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
            self.leadng.constant = -(self.vwObj.frame.size.width)
        })
    })
```

This is the code i am using for animating a UIView. What i am trying to do is to animate the UIView n number of times. That can be done using UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(3.0), but the problem is i am having an array of different images which i want to show within the UiView for each animation. Anyone having any idea about how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use the `animatedImage` property of `UIImage` to animate multiple images inside a imageview.

```
ImageView.image = UIImage.animatedImage(with: myImages, duration: 1.0)
```

where `myImages` is array of images you want to animate.
Follow this [link](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Animating-A-Sequence-of-Images) for details.

Edit: Definitely a very crude way, but it works.

Declared this at top of class.

```
let arrayColors = [UIColor.red , UIColor.green, UIColor.blue]
var animationCount = 0
```

I called animateView() in viewdidload

```
func animateView() {
    self.vwObj.backgroundColor = arrayColors[animationCount]
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
        self.leadng.constant = self.view.frame.size.width + self.vwObj.frame.size.width
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: { finished in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
            self.leadng.constant =  0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.animationCount = self.animationCount + 1
                if self.animationCount < 3 {
                    self.animateView()
                }
        })
    })
}
```

Insted of array of colors, you can use array of images to set imageview.image = arrayImage[animationCount]

Comment: I want to display only a single image within the UIView. But the Image will change based on the array index , everytime the Uiview starts animating

Comment: So you want the imageView to change image after 3 seconds ? and then again after 3 seconds, is it ?

Comment: Yes, rightly so..is there a way to keep track of the counter of the UIView Animation or anything else which might help

Answer (score 0):

Seems solved by the below code:

UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
            print ("Animation Started")
            self.leadng.constant = self.view.frame.size.width + self.vwObj.frame.size.width
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
           print ("BeginCounter --- (self.counter)")

```
    }, completion: { finished in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.5, animations: {
            self.leadng.constant = -(self.vwObj.frame.size.width)

            print ("AnimationCompleted")
            self.counter = self.counter + 1
            print ("CompleteCounter --- \(self.counter)")
            //self.displayAnimation()

            if (self.counter == 3) {

                self.timer?.invalidate()
                self.counter = 0
            }
        })


    })
```

& calling----  timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.displayAnimation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)